# Flutter: How to manage multiple Firebase projects?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have two Firebase projects: a development project and a production project. Two `google-services.json` files.

Now, if you want to work on the production project, you place the production `google-services.json` file in the appropriate folder and use this code in `main.dart`

```
  if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  }
```

If you want to use the development project, you switch the `google-services.json` and use this code in `main.dart`

```
  if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: "Dev",
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  }
```

I want to give the dev team only access to the developers' environment and I'll have access to the production project but I want a way to do this switch via the command line.

This approach has multiple issues, it requires a lot of file switching, I can automate this by writing a bash or PowerShell script to copy the file before doing the build, but still, it's problematic, one has to remember to change the application name and switch files.

Is there a better way of doing this process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are better ways of doing it. Read about (google) `Flutter flavors` and perhaps (probably) in combination with the `--dart-define` option which can be used to make flavors even more powerful.

There are several guides online.